# having problem while getting data from API in react native

Tags: react-native

i am trying to render data from api (type:GET)but while i am trying to setstate of it can not set my state ...here is code of my state and  api call

```
constructor(props) {


super()
 constructor(props) {
        super(){this.state={gender:{}}
```

now here is my api call

```
componentDidMount()
    {
axios.get("http://172.104.217.178/blaze10/public/api/genders")
.then((response) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    this.setState({
        gender:response.data


    });
    alert(this.state.gender)

})
.catch(error => alert(JSON.stringify(error.response.data)));
     }
```

here is my code which i writ in my render function

```
let gender = [];
  let stateGender = this.state.gender;
  alert(JSON.stringify(this.state.gender));
    stateGender.forEach((value, key) => {
        gender.push(<Picker.Item label={key} value={value} />);
    });

and this is my picker components code where i want to show my api data ..
<Item picker >
        <Left>
       <Text style={{paddingLeft:10,fontSize:15,fontWeight:'bold',color:this.state.backgroundColor2}}> Gender</Text>
       </Left>
       <Body>
          <Picker 
            mode="dropdown"
            iosIcon={<Icon name="ios-arrow-down-outline" />}
            style={{ width: '100%' }}

            placeholder="Select Gender"

            placeholderStyle={{ color: "#bfc6ea" }}
            placeholderIconColor="#007aff"
            selectedValue={this.state.gender1}
            onValueChange={(value)=>this.onValueChange(value,'gender')}


          >
            {/* {gender} */}
          </Picker>
          </Body>
        </Item>
```

**facing problems**

1. my state can not updae
2. and when i trying to run my application it gives my error like this TypeError:stateGender is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things that are happening in your code.

First of all, when using the constructor of the Component, pass on the props to super:

From the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor)

> The constructor for a React component is called before it is mounted.
>   When implementing the constructor for a React.Component subclass, you
>   should call super(props) before any other statement. Otherwise,
>   this.props will be undefined in the constructor, which can lead to
>   bugs.

Replace:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(){this.state={gender:{}}
```

with:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    {this.state={gender:{}}
}
```

Second, When you call successfully your api, you are setting the state correctly with setState, but you are popping up an alert with the value of state and you cannot guarantee the state has been set.

This happens here:

```
this.setState({
    gender:response.data
});
alert(this.state.gender)
```

This might or might not work because of this:

From the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
>   componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater,
>   callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
>   has been applied.

Now, when you are rendering your component you are doing this:

```
let gender = [];
let stateGender = this.state.gender;
stateGender.forEach((value, key) => {
    gender.push(<Picker.Item label={key} value={value} />);
});
```

Since stateGender is an object (you initialised it as `this.state={gender:{}}`), you cannot iterate it using forEach directly, but rather using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the keys of the object and then iterating over the keys of the object. Also, make sure that `stateGender` is initialised:

```
if(stateGender){
    Object.keys(stateGender).forEach((key) => {
        if(stateGender.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            gender.push(<Picker.Item label={key} value={stateGender[key]} />);
        }
    });
}
```

**Suggestion**

I strongly suggest you replace this line in your render:

```
{/* {gender} */}
```

with this:

```
{
Object.keys(stateGender).forEach((key) => {
    if(stateGender.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        return (<Picker.Item label={key} value={stateGender[key]} />);
    }
});
}
```

So you don't need the `gender` variable.
Don't forget to validate if `stateGender` is not undefined and it's an object or it has keys.

Your component should look something like this:

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { gender:{} }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("http://172.104.217.178/blaze10/public/api/genders")
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          gender: response.data
        });
      })
      .catch(error => alert(error.message));
  }

  render(){
    let stateGender = this.state.gender;
    // To test if stateGender has keys. If the following alert doesn't return anything, then it will never render the items.
    alert('keys: ' + JSON.stringify(Object.keys(stateGender))); 

    return(
    <View>
      <Left>
        <Text style={{ paddingLeft: 10, fontSize: 15, fontWeight: 'bold', color: this.state.backgroundColor2 }}> Gender</Text>
      </Left>
      <Body>
        <Picker
          mode="dropdown"
          iosIcon={<Icon name="ios-arrow-down-outline" />}
          style={{ width: '100%' }}
          placeholder="Select Gender"
          placeholderStyle={{ color: "#bfc6ea" }}
          placeholderIconColor="#007aff"
          selectedValue={this.state.gender1}
          onValueChange={(value) => this.onValueChange(value, 'gender')}>
          {
            Object.keys(stateGender).forEach((key) => {
              if (stateGender.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                return (<Picker.Item label={key} value={stateGender[key]} />);
              }
            })
          }
        </Picker>
      </Body>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: your ans elemninate the error but still i didn't get any thing in picker :( my bad luck

Comment: but u explained very well May GOD bless you

Comment: @bilalahmad123456 there has to be another problem with the response data. After your axios call, inside `.then((response) => {` can you do this: `alert(JSON.stringify(response.data));`? does it show anything?

Comment: yes i show me all data but when i tried to pass it into picker it show nothing

Comment: @bilalahmad123456 I've edited the answer to include example on how it should look like. Do you have something different than what I've added at the end?

Comment: thanks man i have added your ans but my expo not working now may be internet issue but i marked your and true..thanks for your help and your explanation...thanks buddy stay blesses